# Trying to understand this assembly x86 code

Tags: assembly, x86

I am currently working on defusing a bomb and am on the fourth phase of the bomb, but I have run into a problem. I am not sure what this part of the code means.

```
    0x08048f64 <phase_4+81>:        mov    0x804a20c(,%edx,4),%eax
    0x08048f6b <phase_4+88>:        jmp    *%eax
```

I think that this line of code means to input some line of code into $eax and jump to it, but not so sure though since I do not know what value s at 0x804a20c. I am a little new to assembly. So far I know that the input has to consist of two numbers and that the second number has to be 126. I am not sure what the first number has to be though. Everytime I run the code with numbers x and 126. X being any number I get to the final step, but in that step it compares the value of 0 in -0x8(ebp) to the length of the string. Since on line 56 it inputs 0 into -0x8(ebp). I am wondering if the above code has anything to do with this.

For example, if I input "100 126" then the program will compare the values of 7 to 0 and not let me jump the last explosion on line 191.

Here's the full code.

```
    0x08048f13 <phase_4+0>: push   %ebp
    0x08048f14 <phase_4+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
    0x08048f16 <phase_4+3>: push   %ebx
    0x08048f17 <phase_4+4>: sub    $0x24,%esp
    0x08048f1a <phase_4+7>: lea    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048f1d <phase_4+10>:        mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
    0x08048f21 <phase_4+14>:        lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048f24 <phase_4+17>:        mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
    0x08048f28 <phase_4+21>:        movl   $0x804a206,0x4(%esp)
    0x08048f30 <phase_4+29>:        mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048f33 <phase_4+32>:        mov    %eax,(%esp)
    0x08048f36 <phase_4+35>:        call   0x8048b10 <sscanf@plt>
    0x08048f3b <phase_4+40>:        cmp    $0x2,%eax
    0x08048f3e <phase_4+43>:        je     0x8048f45 <phase_4+50>
    0x08048f40 <phase_4+45>:        call   0x8049e74 <explosion>
    0x08048f45 <phase_4+50>:        mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048f48 <phase_4+53>:        mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x08048f4b <phase_4+56>:        movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
    0x08048f52 <phase_4+63>:        mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048f55 <phase_4+66>:        sub    $0x74,%eax
    0x08048f58 <phase_4+69>:        mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
    0x08048f5b <phase_4+72>:        cmpl   $0xa,-0x18(%ebp)
    0x08048f5f <phase_4+76>:        ja     0x8048fb5 <phase_4+162>
    0x08048f61 <phase_4+78>:        mov    -0x18(%ebp),%edx
    0x08048f64 <phase_4+81>:        mov    0x804a20c(,%edx,4),%eax
    0x08048f6b <phase_4+88>:        jmp    *%eax
    0x08048f6d <phase_4+90>:        addl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
    0x08048f71 <phase_4+94>:        movl   $0x72,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x08048f78 <phase_4+101>:       shll   -0x8(%ebp)
    0x08048f7b <phase_4+104>:       jmp    0x8048fba <phase_4+167>
    0x08048f7d <phase_4+106>:       addl   $0x38,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x08048f81 <phase_4+110>:       addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x08048f85 <phase_4+114>:       movl   $0x7a,-0x8(%ebp)
    0x08048f8c <phase_4+121>:       jmp    0x8048fba <phase_4+167>
    0x08048f8e <phase_4+123>:       movl   $0x44,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x08048f95 <phase_4+130>:       subl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x08048f99 <phase_4+134>:       shll   -0x8(%ebp)
    0x08048f9c <phase_4+137>:       jmp    0x8048fba <phase_4+167>
    0x08048f9e <phase_4+139>:       subl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
    0x08048fa2 <phase_4+143>:       subl   $0x7a,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x08048fa6 <phase_4+147>:       jmp    0x8048fba <phase_4+167>
    0x08048fa8 <phase_4+149>:       movl   $0x3,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x08048faf <phase_4+156>:       addl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
    0x08048fb3 <phase_4+160>:       jmp    0x8048fba <phase_4+167>
    0x08048fb5 <phase_4+162>:       call   0x8049e74 <explosion>
    0x08048fba <phase_4+167>:       mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048fbd <phase_4+170>:       imul   -0x8(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048fc1 <phase_4+174>:       mov    %eax,%ebx
    0x08048fc3 <phase_4+176>:       mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048fc6 <phase_4+179>:       mov    %eax,(%esp)
    0x08048fc9 <phase_4+182>:       call   0x8048a20 <strlen@plt>
    0x08048fce <phase_4+187>:       cmp    %eax,%ebx
    0x08048fd0 <phase_4+189>:       je     0x8048fd7 <phase_4+196>
    0x08048fd2 <phase_4+191>:       call   0x8049e74 <explosion>
    0x08048fd7 <phase_4+196>:       add    $0x24,%esp
    0x08048fda <phase_4+199>:       pop    %ebx
    0x08048fdb <phase_4+200>:       pop    %ebp
    0x08048fdc <phase_4+201>:       ret
```

any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does not look like `x86`

Comment: Looks odd for perhaps a 'Windows dude', but I see now that it's okay for others.

Comment: @Roman R.: this is AT&T syntax. Here's a comparison between it and intel's one: http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm

Comment: So, `mov 0x804a20c(,%edx,4),%eax` looks like `mov eax, [0x804a20c + edx * 4]` for me. Sounds like a jump to an address from table of items. `0x804a20c` should be an array to 32-bit code locations with code to execute. What that a question?

Comment: +1 for "working on defusing a bomb". Got my attention.   (-1 for no "as a homework assignment")

Comment: Immediately looked like x86 (ugly) to me. :)

Answer (score 5):

What is at 804a20c is inconsequential, because the address from which the jump is loaded depends on what is in edx. The address is actually the base of a jump table that is indexed by edx. The address jumped to in the second line is the address in memory at 804a20c+(edx*4).

Comment: Thank you it makes sense. I kept staring at it and wondering what it meant.